# How does chrome identifies where to send which data when multiple tabs are opened?

Tags: networking, operating-system, network-programming

I open two youtube tabs inside a single chrome window and in one tab i am listening to a song and on another an educational video.

How does chromes knows where to send the specific data (for song and video)as both tabs are having same ip address & port number?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Welcome to stackoverflow!!

you're right about (IP+port) needed to reach a particular process on your host. But that process might delegate the task to either another worker process or a thread(depending on browser implementation), and keeps a mapping of the threadID and the HTTP connection

However this statement is wrong

> both tabs are having same ip address & port number

each tab might have its own process and will have a pid.

Comment: So the data sent to the tabs depend on the process id ( and thread id) and corresponding protocol.